# Twitter bot with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I am trying to create a Twitter bot with Ruby on Rails but I just dont find any useful information on this manner... 
Is it posible?
I tried with the GEM twibot but it is deprecated it is not longer useful.
Does Rails have a method for trigger events when (for example) a twit is posted?
Anyone have worked with something like this? 
Any tutorial?
Any information at all that is in current use, I mean that does work today with the Twitter API (Many of the stuff I googled does not work now)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter itself is running on Rails, and it has a [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api). You could easily write your own solution with [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html)

You can get started with the [ActiveResource videos on Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=19)

Comment: Thanks. Any other hint than use ActiveResource, I am asking cause I dont know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

rails per se does not have any support for twitter. it's just an mvc-web-framework. but there are a lot of ruby gems for twitter. my favorite is this https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter but you can find a lot more here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients.html